# How to modify phtml file of a custom module in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Given a custom or a purchased module, 
How do you modify a phtml file without editing the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Follow Below Instructions :

1. You want to override any `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/templates/frontend/form.phtml` You need to override **.PHTML** file in your theme like this:
2. Override in your theme: `app/design/frontend/Theme_Name/Vendor_Module/view/templates/frontend/form.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done similarly to overriding a core phtml files from within a theme.

Instead of for example `Magento_Catalog/templates/view.phtml` where Magento Catalog is the vendor/module a third party module can be overridden by placing custom phtml file within theme under `Vendor_Module` folder:

> app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/ThemeFolder/Vendor_Module/templates/template.phtml

In this case this will override below phml file for the module `Vendor/Module`:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/template.phtml

Comment: Just out of curiousity did you put it in frontend folder within your theme as my answer slightly different to one above? I do not normally use frontend folder within theme as theme is within frontend folder.

Comment: I think it depends on the intervention area of ​​the phtml file that can be frontend or adminhtml

Comment: Yeah i mean the last folder. Does it work like so: Vendor_Module/view/templates/frontend/template.phtml or did you put it in Vendor_Module/templates/template.phtml

Comment: Actually the last frontend folder does not work.

Comment: Yeah i didn't think that was correct.